# What are the files involved in Tesseract-OCR training, and what do they contain?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I want to imitate how Tesseract-OCR train their LSTM-based model. I was trying to read its documentations, but they provided so few details about their architecture (data pre-processing, how different --psm flags are handled).

I learned that their LSTM models are mainly `1 CNN + 1 MaxPooling + 4 LSTM`, for example:
`[1,0,0,3 Ct5,5,16 Mp3,3 Lfys64 Lfx128 Lrx128 Lfx256 O1c105]`
The first 4 numbers are `[batch, height, width, depth]`, while `Ct5,5,16` is a CNN with `kernel_size=5, n_filters=16`, `Mp3,3` is a 3x3 Maxpooling layer, `Lfys, Lfx, Lrx, Lfx` are 4 LSTM layers.

However, what I am not clear about Tesseract's pipeline is the roles of different files used for training `(traineddata, unicharset, lstm, lstmf, ...)`.

As far as I know, we have to prepare raw training data in the form of: `.gt.txt` for line text files, `.box` for bounding box files, `.tif` for line image files. But these datas are not direct input for the training process, but need to be combined to create other files.

My question is, what do these files contain? Are they still the raw input datas, or are they processed by a CNN feature extractor or some image-processing techniques, so that the input for the first `Ct5,5,16` layer is no longer an image, but rather some feature maps?

If possible, could you give me detailed informations about these (what they contain, what they are used for): .lstm, .lstmf, recoder, LSTM Recognizer (I see this word being mentioned sometimes in the doc, but couldn't find any info about it). Thank you so much!